# SP2013 AD and import

Tags: 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

I noticed without configuring the sync user profile service the name and telephone number come from the AD ( domain\newUser, Some Number, New User Name ).  Why not the email ( or other camps)? is this some sort of AD configuration or Sharepoint default action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior, you will need to map AD fields to User Profile properties manually in the UPS to retrieve other values.

Comment: Stop following me! :P
oh wait no don't, just in case I need something else. Thanks :)